# Make Autocomplete ignore a word

Tags: org-mode, completion, auto-complete-mode

I just got started with Emacs for around 1 week or so and I have the following question: can I make Auto Complete ignore a certain word (in a certain major mode)?

Concrete example: I was writing in a file in Org mode a sort of "tutorial" for my use and I wrote about the `<sTAB` command which inserts a code snippet. Now whenever I open a file in Org mode and write `<s`, it offers the completion.

As I prefer commiting completions with the `TAB` key, my only choice is to `C-g` the completion list and then `TAB`.

Moreover, I think that this could serve me well for other cases also. So is it possible to make `auto-complete-mode` *always* ignore a certain word in a certain major mode?

If it's difficult enough to implement, where can I find the actual list of completions which is created? I could visit it and erase `<sTAB`. I'll never write it again. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `ac-stop-words` will be what you are searching for.

cf. https://github.com/auto-complete/auto-complete/blob/master/doc/manual.md#stop-completion-automatically-after-inserting-specific-words

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for that, actually I read about the feature in the manual. But I was thinking that the stop words stop the *service* overall, just like disabling the minor mode. Will test and revert.

Comment: Nope, doesn't work. I edited the example in the manual for the org-mode-hook, tried my "<s" word and even a general one like "this" but doesn't do anything, in fact. Maybe a bug. I'm thinking about switching to company, for other reasons as well.

Comment: hmm..while you are switching, for the record, this variable seems to work. With "th" input pops candidates like "the" in my emacs org-mode, and setting `(add-to-list 'ac-stop-words "th")` makes it silent. ("<S" doesn't pops any candidates for me, maybe some ac-sources difference...?)

Comment: Alright. "th" doesn't work for me either. For ac-sources I have words-in-the-same-mode-buffers. I don't know, there may be other conflicting options in my init file, due to my lack of experience. But nevertheless, I'll be accepting the answer, since you helped me find the appropriate variable. Thanks!